# Substracting minutes from time (in 24 hour format)?

Tags: r

Was wondering if some could help

```
time <-c("16:09", "05:26", "08:47", "03:04", "03:07", "02:01")
min <-c(60, 5, 124, 35, 400, 2)
```

I want to extract a revised time with nth element of vector "min" subtracted from the nth element of vector "time". So for example the 1st element of vector "revised.time" should be 15.09 after subtracting 60 mins.

Thanks in advance

A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to format your time vector first. Then you can substract seconds like this:

```
time2<-strptime(time, "%H:%M")
time2[1]-(60*60)

[1] "2015-10-19 15:09:00 CEST"
```

Answer (score 2):

This should give you what you're looking for, but you may want to consider a dedicated package:

```
time <- c("16:09", "05:26", "08:47", "03:04", "03:07", "02:01")
min  <- c(60, 5, 124, 35, 400, 2)

format(strptime(time, "%M:%S") - min, "%M:%S")
# [1] "15:09" "05:21" "06:43" "02:29" "56:27" "01:59"
```

Comment: Hi there this works fine for most except for element 5 - gives a time of "56:27" rather than time in a 24 hour format?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in lubridate

```
library(lubridate)

hm(time) - new_period(minute = min)
```